Cannot initialize a mongodb replica set on Docker using "docker-compose.yaml" file
I already tried to find similar questions, but those do not seem to resolve my issue. My issue is very similar, but my configuration is already good as per this related issues:
Cannot initialize a mongodb replica set on Docker
MongoDB replica set initiate() failing on Docker
https://dev.to/mattdark/deploy-a-mongodb-cluster-with-docker-compose-4ieo

I want to set up locally a MongoDB cluster using Docker.
I have the following docker-compose.yaml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongo_replica_1:
        container_name: mongo_replica_1
        hostname: mongo_replica_1
        image: mongo:7.0.4
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['mongod', '--bind_ip', 'localhost,mongo_replica_1', '--replSet', 'dbrs', '--dbpath', '/data/db']
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
    mongo_replica_2:
        container_name: mongo_replica_2
        hostname: mongo_replica_2
        image: mongo:7.0.4
        ports:
            - 27018:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['mongod', '--bind_ip', 'localhost,mongo_replica_2', '--replSet', 'dbrs', '--dbpath', '/data/db']
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
    mongo_replica_3:
        container_name: mongo_replica_3
        hostname: mongo_replica_3
        image: mongo:7.0.4
        ports:
            - 27019:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['mongod', '--bind_ip', 'localhost,mongo_replica_3', '--replSet', 'dbrs', '--dbpath', '/data/db']
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
    mongo_launcher:
        container_name: mongo_launcher
        image: mongo:7.0.4
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            - mongo_replica_1
            - mongo_replica_2
            - mongo_replica_3
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - ./scripts/mongo-setup.sh:/scripts/mongo-setup.sh
        entrypoint: ['sh', '/scripts/mongo-setup.sh']

networks:
    dashboard_network:
        driver: bridge

This is my mongo-setup.sh file:
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB_REPLICA_1=mongo_replica_1
MONGODB_REPLICA_2=mongo_replica_2
MONGODB_REPLICA_3=mongo_replica_3

echo "************ [ Waiting for startup ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

until mongosh --host ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017 --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())"; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo "************ [ Startup completed ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

mongosh --host ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017 <<EOF
var configuration = {
    "_id": "dbrs",
    "protocolVersion": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017",
            "priority": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_2}:27018",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_3}:27019",
            "priority": 1
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "chainingAllowed": true
    }
};
rs.initiate(configuration);
rs.secondaryOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
EOF 

Then I try to connect to the DB with string mongodb://localhost:27017 but it fails: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 
So I tried to inspect my mongo_launcher container:
MongoServerError: replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: mongo_replica_2:27018 failed with Error connecting to mongo_replica_2:27018 (172.24.0.2:27018) :: caused by :: onInvoke :: caused by :: Connection refused, mongo_replica_3:27019 failed with Error connecting to mongo_replica_3:27019 (172.24.0.3:27019) :: caused by :: onInvoke :: caused by :: Connection refused
test> DeprecationWarning: .setSecondaryOk() is deprecated. Use .setReadPref("primaryPreferred") instead
Setting read preference from "primary" to "primaryPreferred"

And inspected one of the replica set container:
{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"oplog.rs","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"local"}}}

